# Using Twig to generate JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json, twig

I want to have a URL that returns a simple JSON object. I am trying to use Twig to generate the JSON object:

```
{
"urls": [
{% for child in page.root %}
    "{{ child.url }}"{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
]
}
```

The carriage returns will not remain in place though, and I keep getting a result that looks like this:

```
{'urls':['../ants/','../brick-report/','../the-pollution-intervention/','../barclay/','../broken-advertising/','../aldat-n-densom/','../thisisart/','../there-she-goes-again/']}
```

which Jquery will not parse with it's ajax or getJSON methods. It's totally ignoring this JSON. How might I convince Twig to put the right whitespace in place? I've looked at the manual and it only seems concerned with NOT inserting whitespace.

Comment: I'm personally wondering how the single quotes are traded for the double quotes in your code.. single quoted json properties are invalid.  Also, whitespace isn't a requirement for valid json.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I asked this question too soon. Valid JSON does not require the whitespace--it does require the quotes to be around the property name of the object, which I was not doing.

Answer (score 15):

This works for me (twig template):

```
var parsedJSON = JSON.parse('{{ ['one', 'two', 'three']|json_encode|e('js') }}');
```

And this:

```
console.log(parsedJSON);
```

outputs:

```
 Array ["one", "two", "three"]
```

in browser's console.

Answer (score 6):

Twig has a filter for this.

[json_encode](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/json_encode.html), it uses PHP json_encode function.

for your case:

```
{{ {'urls': page.root}|json_encode }}
```

will output

```
{"urls":["..\/ants\/","..\/brick-report\/","..\/the-pollution-intervention\/","..\/barclay\/","..\/broken-advertising\/","..\/aldat-n-densom\/","..\/thisisart\/","..\/there-she-goes-again\/"]}
```

the code is tested and works. For more information take a look at the Twig Documentation for [json_encode](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/json_encode.html).

Answer (score 4):

Generally it would make more sense to make controller return json directly, by returning `JsonRespnse` object

But if you really need to output JSON in Twig and assign it to variable, you can also use:

```
let foo = {{ bar|json_encode|raw }}
```

Comment: If one only uses said json in JavaScript, I would *highly* advise anyone to use @biera s answer, as the missing encoding here can create problems further down the line, when dealing with newlines for example.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use Twig to generate your json response.

In your controller, use:

```
return new Response(json_encode($var));
```

Sample:

```
public function sampleAction()
{
    $urls = array('../test', '../something', '../sample');
    return new Response(json_encode($var));
}
```

If URLs are generated from Symfony2 routes, you can use:

```
public function sampleAction()
{
    $urls = array(
             $this->generateUrl('my_test'),
             $this->generateUrl('my_something'),
             $this->generateUrl('my_sample'),
    );
    return new Response(json_encode($var));
}
```

Comment: That's not suitable when already using twig to construct a response.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your template in an autoescape block:

```
{% autoescape 'js' %}
  { "href": "{{ my_url }}" }
{% endautoescape%}
```

Answer (score -1):

Thats easy if you extend twig.

First, create a class that will contain the extension:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Twig\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;  
use \Twig_Extension;

class VarsExtension extends Twig_Extension
{
    protected $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container) 
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function getName() 
    {
        return 'some.extension';
    }

    public function getFilters() {
        return array(
            'json_decode'   => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'jsonDecode'),
        );
    }

    public function jsonDecode($str) {
        return json_decode($str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please continue this answer by finishing your extension and giving a usage sample that fits OP requirements.

Answer (score -2):

Basically the **$.getJson()** method requires json but ther is a string
so you can use **$.get()** to get the response and use the parser to parse the string to JSON

```
 $.get("ffff",function(data){
 // user parser
 JSON.parse();
 });
```